# Sublime Text syntax highlighting html files as babel/javascript

Tags: sublimetext3, babeljs, syntax-highlighting

Now that I have Babel installed for my React development I noticed that when I open `.html` files the syntax highlighting is set to javascript (babel) instead of HTML. How can I fix this? Here are also a couple of images that might help. Also a little extra thing, I am using the Afterglow theme for sublime text, and how can I remove the annoying padding on the last image underneath the tabs? You can see a few pixels of space which really annoys me.

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: What I want is, that when I open an HTML file it has the correct syntax highlighting set to HTML and not javascript (Babel), and for the padding, it would be great to simply remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably overridden the default language settings for HTML files. You can verify this in the *Syntax* settings.

1. Open the *View* menu
2. Open the *Syntax* sub-menu
3. Open the settings for HTML

If my assumption is true, edit (or delete?) the settings for HTML.

Otherwise, you can assign a syntax to an extension through the same menu.

1. Open a HTML file
2. Open the *View* menu
3. Open the *Syntax* sub-menu
4. Select HTML in the *Open all files with current extension as…* sub-menu

Comment: Thank you, followed the steps and it worked perfectly. Had to restart sublime text though but it works now :D

Comment: Any ideas on how to remove the padding underneath the tabs?

Comment: Also, how can I make the text when I press `ctrl + r`  bigger? Any ideas?

Comment: I've never experienced that padding before. Maybe caused by a theme or package?

Comment: Yes but isnt there a way to fix it?

Comment: I'd ask on the Sublime Text forum, maybe someone has an idea